# Affect the final alpha of combined draw calls

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
var p = context.image { ctx in
    ctx.cgContext.setAlpha(0.5)
    UIColor(hue: 0.2, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).setFill()
    let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), cornerRadius: 10)
    let q = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200), cornerRadius: 10)
    p.fill()
    q.fill()
}
```

Except, I want the `ctx.cgContext.setAlpha(0.5)` not to act as a multiplier for the individual `fills` but rather apply alpha to the combined rendered output of the two subsequent calls. It would be like rendering without the `ctx.cgContext.setAlpha(0.5)` and then taking the result and applying alpha to it (which creates a different image), sorta like the draw calls were on a pre-rendered layer.

I can't find a way to do this in Core Graphics without actually rendering an entirely separate image and then drawing that image into the context, which doesn't feel right. Perhaps there isn't a way?

Comment: There may be a couple different options... but, it would help if you provided a complete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is what [Transparency Layers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html) are for. The example in this document sets a shadow that applies to two shapes, but you would set the context's alpha (just as you do in your code above).

Comment: @KurtRevis that looks like what I needed. Feel free to make that an answer so I can accept it!